# Multiplication of two fields in salesforce using trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning

I am new to salesforce. I tried multiplying two fields from two different objects but was failed to do so.

I have two objects object 1 and object 2 as given below:
object 1 is child of object 2.
Object 1: EncMastData__C
Object 2: ChecEnc__C
On EncMastData__C one field is there called itemvalue.
on ChecEnc__C two fields were there called quantity and refund.
i want refund to be populated with itemvalue * quantity using trigger.Formula field should not be used here.

Below code i tried:

---

```
trigger AutopopulateRefund on ChecEnc__C (after insert,after update) {
    List<ChecEnc__C> encUpdatelist = new List<ChecEnc__C>();            
    List<ChecEnc__C> lstEnclsVal = [select id,Quantity__c,EncMastData__r.Item_Value__c,Refund__c from ChecEnc__C where id=:trigger.new];  
            if(lstEnclsVal.size()>0){
                    for(ChecEnc__C EncLst : lstEnclsVal){
                    ChecEnc__C newEnc = new ChecEnc__C();  
                    newEnc.Refund__c = EncLst.EncMastData__r.Item_Value__c * EncLst.Quantity__c;
                    encUpdatelist.add(newEnc);
            }
                update encUpdatelist;
            }
   
}
```

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your post.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe the _specific problem_, including any error messages verbatim.

Comment: I suspect that the issue is that `newEnc` is never given an Id, so the DML update is failing (records need an Id to be able to be updated), but I'd rather see that error message before writing an answer.

Comment: Also `id=:trigger.new`. Does it even compile?

Comment: @metasync the `id = :<sobject list here>` construction is allowed by Salesforce (just syntactic sugar).

Comment: @DerekF   which Id do I need to consider here.in debug logs I am getting the values but updation only not happening.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include the full text of the error you're getting, verbatim (don't change, add, or remove any words).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your code ended up working, you'd run into a recursive loop. You should use before insert/before update, and set the value directly. You'll need to query the parent record(s), then perform the math:

```
trigger AutopopulateRefund on ChecEnc__c (before insert, before update) {
  Map<Id, EncMasterData__c> parents = new Map<Id, EncMasterData__c>();
  for(ChecEnc__c record: Trigger.new) {
    parents.put(record.EncMasterData__c, null);
  }
  parents.putAll([SELECT Item_Value__c FROM EncMasterData__c WHERE Id = :parents.keySet()]);
  for(ChecEnc__c record: Trigger.new) {
    EncMasterData__c parent = parents.get(record.EncMasterData__c);
    if(parent?.Item_Value__c != null && record.Quantity__c != null) {
      record.Refund__c = parent.Item_Value__c * record.Quantity__c;
    }
  }
}
```

I made an assumption on what the parent object is called; you will need to adjust this name accordingly.